# How to use OR operator in flutter firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore field can contain either the value of gender as ‘MEN’, ‘WOMEN’ or ‘UNISEX’. So I want to get the documents where the field is either MEN or WOMEN.

```
QuerySnapshot snap = await myReference.where('gender',isEqualTo:'MEN').limit(6).get();
```

How can I extend this query for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereIn` operator to get documents for required genders.

```
QuerySnapshot snap = await myReference.where('gender', whereIn:['MEN', 'WOMEN']).limit(6).get();
```

This query will fetch documents where the field gender is equal to either of the values mentioned in that array passed as value of `whereIn`

Answer (score 0):

As Dharmaraj mentioned, Cloud Firestore is now supported IN operator. you can use WhereIN operator that support up to 10 comparison values.
the code could be :

```
QuerySnapshot snap = await myReference.where('gender',whereIn:['MEN','WOMEN','UNISEX']).limit(6).get();
```

**Note**: this soultion has some other limitations as written in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2)